# recyclerView custom adapter binditem gets called when inserting into database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app displays playlists where for each playlist I show albumart in recyclerview.
A custom adapter displays the rows. It all works fine but when I add another playlist, using an asynctask, the display gets redrawn several times. I have checked that there are no adapter.notifydatasetchanged() calls. Stepping through the code I have discovered that it happens when there is a resolver.insert

In this example, the routine creates a new playlist, either for whole albums or tracks.

```
        public void addTracksToPlaylist(Context context, String music_id,
                                long playlist_id, String nmode, int base) {
    // feed it the album_id or track_id
    Uri mediauri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();


    Uri exturi = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
            "external", playlist_id);
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK};
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID + " =?";
    String orderBy = null;
    if (nmode.equals(context.getString(R.string.track_mode))) {
        where = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";

    }
    orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " ASC, "
            + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " ASC , " +
            "CAST(" + (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK) + " AS INTEGER) ASC";
    String[] whereVal = {music_id};

    Cursor c = resolver.query(mediauri, projection, where, whereVal,
            orderBy);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        boolean stamp = prefs.getstampSelected(context);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String audio_id = c.getString(idColumn);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, base);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audio_id);
            try {
                resolver.insert(exturi, values);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //   String thistrack= track.getfullPathfromAudioId(context,audio_id);
            //  Log.i(TAG,"position : "+base +" Inserted track = "+ audio_id + " track "+thistrack+ " Album_id = "+ music_id);
            base++;
            if (stamp) {
                try {
                    track.updateTrackModifiedDate(audio_id, context);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

What can I do to prevent these actions, which happen in the background, affect the display of playlists. Or in other words, why/how is my recyclerView "active" as it appears to be aware of changes in the database.

Update:
From the Android Developers website:

The Loader will monitor for changes to the data, and report them to you through new calls here. You should not monitor the data yourself. For example, if the data is a Cursor and you place it in a CursorAdapter, use the CursorAdapter(android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor, int) constructor without passing in either FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY or FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (that is, use 0 for the flags argument). This prevents the CursorAdapter from doing its own observing of the Cursor, which is not needed since when a change happens you will get a new Cursor throw another call here.

the monitoring and reporting back by the loader manifests itself in onLoadFinished calls which in my case reset the adapter.

Comment: CursorLoaders will refresh on every change, so your issue is probably with `onLoadFinished` that gets called multiple times, but you did not include any code, so please include your loading logic, too.

Comment: You wrote all this to describe a problem with a recycler view and its adapter, yet you didn’t post the relevant code (the adapter); instead you pasted all irrelevant information about how you prepare your data. :)

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, the Loader monitors changes in the underlying data. The solution was simple in the end. 
I declare a boolean variable

```
       private boolean processing=false;
```

Set the variable to true in the onPreExecute() and to false in onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask.

As a change fires the OnLoadFinished call I test for the value of processing and skip the code. Once completed, I call getLoaderManager().restartLoader etc